# Text color changed after some specific time

Tags: android, time

I want to make time triggered event just like clash of clans upgrades. So I want to change the color of the text after 12 hours from when the user creates a High score in the game how can I achieve this?

Comment: use alarm manager ...........

Comment: after 12 hours, you app may have been kill by system